# Why are some ckeditor table properties not editable?

Tags: ckeditor

If I create a table in ckeditor, and then later go back and edit the post and control-click on the table and select "Table Properties" some of the properties are editable (alignment, width, border) and some are not (rows, columns and most importantly caption). The greyed out table properties are not editable.

Is there a reason why? Is there a way of editing them? Is that a configuration setting?

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say you can't change this behaviour. CKEditor has been designed this way that you manipulate columns and rows of an existing table using the contextmenu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>, then "Row ▶" or "Column ▶").

As for the caption, it's funny because it works for me (tested [version 4.4.7](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/classic.html)) – it's always editable. Which version of CKE are you using? Could you provide a working example?